# Vue how to use v-model on sync prop in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in parent component, I pass a prop using `.sync` to achieve 2-way binding, in child components, I simply bind that prop to a `v-model`, in this way, I hope any change in child component can be propagated to parent through this `.sync` prop. However, I received the warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? According to vue document, `.sync` is designed by 2-way data binding. How should I do this in child components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The child shouldn't use `v-model` on the `prop` that is synced. Instead, it should use `$emit('update:<prop>', value)`. However, it may make even more sense to use `v-model` from the parent and `$emit('input', value)` from the child:

```
// parent implementation
<child-component v-model="first_name" />
```

Then,

```
// child implementation
<template>
  <input type="text" @change="$emit('input', e)" :value="innerValue" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      innerValue: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.innerValue = this.value
  }
}
</script>
```

**Edit**

If you'd like to use the `v-model` approach within the child component, you'll have to use it on the `innerValue` and emit when that changes. We can setup a watcher in the child:

```
// child component
watch: {
  innerValue: function (value) { 
    this.$emit('input', value)
  }
}
```

And then you can use `v-model` on your child's component custom component implementation:

```
// child component
<template>
  <custom-component v-model="innerValue" />
</template>
```